# A textbook reference for an Intersection Theory Result

Tags: reference-request, intersection-theory

I am using the following results:

Given

$M$ a smooth closed orientable manifold and $A$ and $B$ two smooth closed orientable submanifolds. $A$ and $B$ intersect transversely and $\dim A+\dim B=\dim M$.

Then $[A]^*\smile[B]^*=[A\cap B]^*$ holds, where $\smile$ denotes cup product and $[X]$ denotes the homology class of the manifold $[X]$ and $[X]^*$ denotes Poincar\'{e} dual to $[X]$

The accented e of Poincare is not appearing.

Sorry about that.

Comment: Can you find it somewhere in Bott and Tu?

Comment: Yes. The closest I got is the chapter where Poincare duality is revisited. But it's all cryptic to me.